# changed dmf too solid clutch in astra 1.7cdti

Tags: clutch

i have replaced 1.7cdti engine for another 1.7cdti the new 1 came with dual mass so put our solid 1 on now it wont clear gears but will clutch bite if put into gear befre starting there is no air in clutch slave

Comment: Did you fit the centre (clutch) plate the wrong way round? This can give the symptoms you mention...